# Getting precise and accurate location updates indoors on the Apple Watch using Core Location?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, apple-watch

I'm trying to get location updates for workout tracking (indoors) and so I am in need of very precise and constant location updates, but in testing the delegate callbacks don't seem to be very accurate.  For example, moving 20-30 feet doesn't trigger a location update most of the time.  Is there anything in my code below that might cause this inaccuracy?

```
  import CoreLocation

    protocol UserLocationDelegate: class {
        func didUpdateUserLocation(_ manager: WorkoutLocationManager, distance: CLLocationDistance)
    }


    class WorkoutLocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

        deinit {
            self.locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }

        private var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
        var previousLocation: CLLocation?
        weak var userLocationDelgate: UserLocationDelegate?

        public func getUserLocation() {
            guard CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() else {
                print("User does not have location services enabled")
                return
            }

            locationManager = CLLocationManager()
            locationManager?.delegate = self
            locationManager?.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            locationManager?.activityType = .fitness //test as the docs say this will turn OFF indoor tracking

            let locationAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

            switch locationAuthorizationStatus {
            case .authorizedAlways:
                print("location authorized Always")
                locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            case .authorizedWhenInUse:
                print("location authorized When in Use")
                locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            case .denied:
                print("location authorization denied")
                locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            case .notDetermined:
                print("location authorization not determined")
                 locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

            case .restricted:
                print("location authorization restricted")
                 locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

            }

        }


        // MARK: - CLLocationManagerDelegate



        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

            print("did update locations called")

            if previousLocation == nil {
                previousLocation = locations.first
            } else {
                guard let latest = locations.first else { return }
                let distanceInMeters = previousLocation?.distance(from: latest) ?? 0
                if distanceInMeters > 0 {
                    let distanceInFeet = distanceInMeters * 3.28
                    print("distance in feet: \(distanceInFeet)")
                    userLocationDelgate?.didUpdateUserLocation(self, distance: distanceInFeet
                    )
                }
                previousLocation = latest
            }

        }

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
            print("location manager error = \(error)")
        }

    }




import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, UserLocationDelegate {
    func didUpdateUserLocation(_ manager: WorkoutLocationManager, distance: CLLocationDistance) {
        locationLabel.setText("\(distance.rounded().description) feet")
    }


    let workoutLocationManager = WorkoutLocationManager()


    @IBOutlet weak var locationLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        workoutLocationManager.getUserLocation()
        workoutLocationManager.userLocationDelgate = self

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You set `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` as `desiredAccuracy`. There is variable for `CLLocationAccuracy` which should be more accurate

```
kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
```

Comment: But doesn't for Navigation mean for driving as opposed to running etc.?

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it out and see if I get better results.  Another reason I did not use kCLLocationAccuracyBest is the docs say only use when the device is connected to a power source which obviously for a workout use case is not practical.

Comment: @GarySabo you’re right. Anyway, you can try it and you will see. Alternatively you can set your own accuracy without using kCL... variables

Comment: I tested it out, and both kCLLocationAcurracyBest and kCCLocationAccuracyBestForNagivation work well outdoors, but neither will work indoors very well?  I understand the limitations of GPS under a roof but I've used other apps that used only Core Location and are accurate indoors, how are they doing it?

Comment: @GarySabo oh, thats another problem. Can you give me one example of app which work well in indoors? Maybe we can figure out why is that.

Comment: Sure, one I've tried recently that worked well indoors is Fit Life https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fit-life-sports-tracker/id1371444280?mt=8

Comment: @GarySabo and what does this app track in indoors?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185920/discussion-between-garysabo-and-robert-dresler).

Comment: @GarySabo Have you tried using the CoreMotion framework? You could try to calculate a new location based on CLLocation heading and CMPedometer distance.

Comment: @quant24 I've been working on an implementation with CoreMotion's CMPedometer class and it's working pretty well... I'm curious as to what the CLLocation heading would add to this though?  I'm not very familiar with it